# Eclipse code formatter customization

Tags: eclipse, formatter, code-cleanup

I've recently configured my Eclipse Formatter and I'm pretty happy with how it works, except for one thing. I'd like to set it up so my member variables are sorted into 3 distinct group with a blank line between each of the groups. I want the first group to be static final variables (constants), the second to be regular static variables, and in the third I want all the non-static variables (or again split final and non-final ones, I don't mind either way).

For example, I'd like my class to look like this:

```
public class Foo {

    public static final String PATH_TO_BAR = "C:/Drunken/Clam/Bar";
    public static final int N_BARS = 42;

    public static BufferedWriter logger;

    public int foobar;
    public String barfoo;
    private int lengthOfBarFoo;

    ...
}
```

but right now it formats it as

```
public class Foo {

    public static final String PATH_TO_BAR = "C:/Drunken/Clam/Bar";
    public static BufferedWriter logger;
    private int lengthOfBarFoo;
    public String barfoo;
    public static final int N_BARS = 42;
    public int foobar;

    ...
}
```

Is this possible to set up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do that via below :

in eclipse you can sort "Members Sort Order" preference:

> "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order"

you can up and down the choice according to your need. 
 if you have any query or doubt, comment below.

Comment: This almost does what I want, but doesn't put blank lines between the groups. I've tried messing around with Formatter -> Blank Lines -> Before declarations of the same kind, but it still didn't put any blank lines between the groups.

Comment: if it works for you, then you can accept it too., if you can do then may be you can put blank line manually too. it's not time consuming.

Comment: @MatedeVita, if this become helpful to you then you can upvote and accept answer ,and close question.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse save actions](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-save-actions.htm) might come handy here, however not to such of a detail you've been asking for.